# Is there a way I could cancel and restart a function in my COM object?

Tags: com, callback, vb6, activex

**How my software works now:**

I have a C++ ATL object and a VB6 client application. The COM object has a function, `Find`, which searches a database and reports matches via a callback function. I call the `Find` function from VB6 when a user enters text into a TextBox using its Change event, passing the text and the address of a callback function. The callback function outputs matches to a ListBox, makes a `DoEvents` call, and returns a value indicating if the search should continue.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

When a user changes the text in the search field while a search is already running, I want to cancel the running search, empty the ListBox, and start a new one with the updated text.

**The problem I'm running into:**

Because the Change event of the TextBox is fired during the `DoEvents` call in the callback function, a new search is stacked on top of the first before the callback can return a "cancel" code. When this new search has a match, it calls the callback, gets back the cancel code, and then ends, at which point the previous search is resumed.

How could I possibly cancel the old search before starting a new one automatically?

**Code:**

```
Private Sub txtFind_Change()
    lvResults.ListItems.Clear
    m_customer.CancelFind #' Not useful
    frmMain.appData.Licfile.Find(txtFind.Text, AddressOf FindCallback, ObjPtr(m_customer))
End Sub

Public Function CancelFind()
    If m_bFindRunning Then: m_bCancelFind = True
End Function

Public Function FindCallback(ByVal foundItem As Boolean, _
                             ByVal finished As Boolean, _
                             ByVal index As Long) As Long
Dim record As zLicFileRecord
Dim resultstr As String
Dim error As Long
    If foundItem Then
        frmMain.appData.Licfile.Read(index, record)
        RaiseEvent SearchResult(index, record)
        DoEvents
    Else
        If Not finished Then
            RaiseEvent SearchProgress(index, frmMain.appData.Licfile.RecordCount)
            DoEvents
        Else
            RaiseEvent SearchFinished
        End If
    End If
    If m_bCancelFind Then
        FindCallback = 1
        m_bCancelFind = False
    End If
End Function


STDMETHODIMP CzLicenseFile::Find(BSTR  find, 
                                 LONG  callbackFunction /* fnFindCallback */,
                                 LONG  context,
                                 LONG* win32Error)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    CHECK_PTR(win32Error);

    if (!callbackFunction)
    {
        *win32Error = ERROR_NO_CALLBACK_ACTIVE;
        RETURN_OK;
    }

    fnFindCallback pfnCallback = reinterpret_cast<fnFindCallback>(callbackFunction);

    try 
    {
        DWORD recordCount;
        get_RecordCount(reinterpret_cast<LONG*>(&recordCount));
        if (recordCount == static_cast<DWORD>(-1))
        {
            *win32Error = ERROR_READ_FAULT;
            RETURN_OK;
        }

        QuickMatcher matcher(std::wstring(find, ::SysStringLen(find)));

        for (size_t i = static_cast<size_t>(startIndex); i < recordCount; ++i)
        {
            LicenseFileRecord const& item = m_fileBuf.Get(i);  

            bool match = matcher.match(item);

            if (match)
            {
                if (pfnCallback)
                {
                    LONG result = pfnCallback(VTRUE, VFALSE, i, context);
                    if (result != 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (i % 1000 == 0)
            {
                if (pfnCallback)
                {
                    LONG result = pfnCallback(VFALSE, VFALSE, i, context);
                    if (result != 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
    }
    catch (AutoWinError const& e)
    {
        *win32Error = e.error();
        RETURN_OK;
    }

    if (pfnCallback)
    {
        pfnCallback(VFALSE, VTRUE, -1, context);
    }

    *win32Error = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    RETURN_OK;
}
```

Comment: Your post is too broad.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without seeing the code.

Comment: I have removed the C++ tag because if clearly does not apply here. Please tag your posts appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with a function and a `Timer` object. `txtFind_Change` now calls this function:

```
Public Sub StartSearch()
Dim error As Long
    lvResults.ListItems.Clear
    If Not m_customer Is Nothing Then
        If Not m_customer.FindRunning Then
            error = frmMain.appData.Licfile.Find(txtFind.Text, AddressOf FindCallback, ObjPtr(m_customer))
        Else
            m_customer.CancelFind
            TimerSearchRestart.Interval = 50
            TimerSearchRestart.enabled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```